# コンパイルエラー undefined reference to `WSAStartup@8'などが発生

Tags: c, mingw

Windows10の環境でC言語プログラム（server.c)を作成し、gcc(MinGW)でコンパイルをしようとしたら、下記のようなコンパイルエラーが発生してしまいます。

```
C:\Users\name\Desktop>gcc server.c -o server
C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGmbeVJ.o:server.c:(.text0x2b) undefined reference to `WSAStartup@8'
```

など「WSAStartup@8」の部分が「socket@12」や「WSAGetLastError@0」や
「htons@4」など場合のエラーが発生してしまいます。

ちなみにヘッダファイルは、

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
```

をしています。

Windows環境でUNIXを使用できる「msys2」や「Cygwin」を使用してのコンパイルはもうすでにやりましたがWindows用プログラムを作成したいのでそちらの方法は避けたいです。

gcc(MinGW)で先ほどのコンパイルエラーがなおる方法をできれば詳しく教えてください。。
「こうするしかない」っていう場合も教えてください。

Comment: ちなみにserver.cプログラムは適当なとこからコピペして作成しました。http://www.geekpage.jp/programming/winsock/tcp-3.php です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

本家Stack Overflowに同様の質問がありました。
[mingw - C - Undefined Reference to WSAStartup@8' - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34384803/c-undefined-reference-to-wsastartup8)

[解決したらしい回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34385112/10216107)によると、Winsockライブラリ（`ws2_32`？）への依存を解決するために`-lws2_32`という引数を追加する必要があるようです。

Comment: できました!!!!　本当にありがとうございます！！！！